# How can I read command line parameters from an R script?

Tags: command-line, r, parameters

I've got a R script for which I'd like to be able to supply several command-line parameters (rather than hardcode parameter values in the code itself).  The script runs on Windows.

I can't find info on how to read parameters supplied on the command-line into my R script.  I'd be surprised if it can't be done, so maybe I'm just not using the best keywords in my Google search...

Any pointers or recommendations?

Comment: you need to set location of rscript executable

Answer (score 220, accepted):

[Dirk's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2151627/8817) is everything you need. Here's a minimal reproducible example.

I made two files: `exmpl.bat` and `exmpl.R`.

- `exmpl.bat`:

  ```
  set R_Script="C:\Program Files\R-3.0.2\bin\RScript.exe"
  %R_Script% exmpl.R 2010-01-28 example 100 > exmpl.batch 2>&1
  ```

  Alternatively, using `Rterm.exe`:

  ```
  set R_TERM="C:\Program Files\R-3.0.2\bin\i386\Rterm.exe"
  %R_TERM% --no-restore --no-save --args 2010-01-28 example 100 < exmpl.R > exmpl.batch 2>&1
  ```
- `exmpl.R`:

  ```
  options(echo=TRUE) # if you want see commands in output file
  args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
  print(args)
  # trailingOnly=TRUE means that only your arguments are returned, check:
  # print(commandArgs(trailingOnly=FALSE))

  start_date <- as.Date(args[1])
  name <- args[2]
  n <- as.integer(args[3])
  rm(args)

  # Some computations:
  x <- rnorm(n)
  png(paste(name,".png",sep=""))
  plot(start_date+(1L:n), x)
  dev.off()

  summary(x)
  ```

Save both files in the same directory and start `exmpl.bat`. In the result you'll get:

- `example.png` with some plot
- `exmpl.batch` with all that was done

You could also add an environment variable `%R_Script%`:

```
"C:\Program Files\R-3.0.2\bin\RScript.exe"
```

and use it in your batch scripts as `%R_Script% <filename.r> <arguments>`

Differences between `RScript` and `Rterm`:

- `Rscript` has simpler syntax
- `Rscript` automatically chooses architecture on x64 (see [R Installation and Administration, 2.6 Sub-architectures](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Sub_002darchitectures) for details)
- `Rscript` needs `options(echo=TRUE)` in the .R file if you want to write the commands to the output file

Answer (score 130):

A few points:

1. Command-line parameters are
   accessible via `commandArgs()`, so
   see `help(commandArgs)` for an
   overview.
2. You can use `Rscript.exe` on all platforms, including Windows. It will support `commandArgs()`. [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) could be ported to Windows but lives right now only on OS X and Linux.
3. There are two add-on packages on CRAN -- [getopt](http://cran.r-project.org/package=getopt) and [optparse](http://cran.r-project.org/package=optparse) -- which were both written for command-line parsing.

*Edit in Nov 2015:*  New alternatives have appeared and I *wholeheartedly* recommend [docopt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/docopt/index.html).

Comment: and there is [argparse](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/argparse/index.html)

Answer (score 99):

Add this to the top of your script:

```
args<-commandArgs(TRUE)
```

Then you can refer to the arguments passed as `args[1]`, `args[2]` etc.

Then run

```
Rscript myscript.R arg1 arg2 arg3
```

If your args are strings with spaces in them, enclose within double quotes.

Comment: This only worked when I used args<-commandArgs(TRUE) (note the uppercase A).

Comment: do you need --args before arg1?

Comment: @philcolbourn No

Answer (score 19):

Since `optparse` has been mentioned a couple of times in the answers, and it provides a comprehensive kit for command line processing, here's a short simplified example of how you can use it, assuming the input file exists:

***script.R:***

```
library(optparse)

option_list <- list(
  make_option(c("-n", "--count_lines"), action="store_true", default=FALSE,
    help="Count the line numbers [default]"),
  make_option(c("-f", "--factor"), type="integer", default=3,
    help="Multiply output by this number [default %default]")
)

parser <- OptionParser(usage="%prog [options] file", option_list=option_list)

args <- parse_args(parser, positional_arguments = 1)
opt <- args$options
file <- args$args

if(opt$count_lines) {
  print(paste(length(readLines(file)) * opt$factor))
}
```

Given an arbitrary file `blah.txt` with 23 lines.

On the command line:

`Rscript script.R -h` *outputs*

```
Usage: script.R [options] file


Options:
        -n, --count_lines
                Count the line numbers [default]

        -f FACTOR, --factor=FACTOR
                Multiply output by this number [default 3]

        -h, --help
                Show this help message and exit
```

`Rscript script.R -n blah.txt` *outputs* `[1] "69"`

`Rscript script.R -n -f 5 blah.txt` *outputs* `[1] "115"`

Answer (score 15):

Try library(getopt) ... if you want things to be nicer. For example:

```
spec <- matrix(c(
        'in'     , 'i', 1, "character", "file from fastq-stats -x (required)",
        'gc'     , 'g', 1, "character", "input gc content file (optional)",
        'out'    , 'o', 1, "character", "output filename (optional)",
        'help'   , 'h', 0, "logical",   "this help"
),ncol=5,byrow=T)

opt = getopt(spec);

if (!is.null(opt$help) || is.null(opt$in)) {
    cat(paste(getopt(spec, usage=T),"\n"));
    q();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

you need [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) (pronounced 'little r')

Dirk will be by in about 15 minutes to elaborate ;)

Answer (score 8):

In bash, you can construct a command line like the following:

```
$ z=10
$ echo $z
10
$ Rscript -e "args<-commandArgs(TRUE);x=args[1]:args[2];x;mean(x);sd(x)" 1 $z
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
[1] 5.5
[1] 3.027650
$
```

You can see that the variable `$z` is substituted by bash shell with "10" and this value is picked up by `commandArgs` and fed into `args[2]`, and the range command `x=1:10` executed by R successfully, etc etc.

Answer (score 4):

FYI:   there is a function args(), which retrieves the arguments of R functions, not to be confused with a vector of arguments named args

Comment: This is almost certainly not the case.  Only functions can mask functions.  Creating a variable with the same name as a function does not mask the function.  Refer to this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6135868/602276

Comment: True, it doesn't mask it. Just in general, I try to avoid naming functions and variables with names that already exist in R.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to specify options with flags, (like -h, --help, --number=42, etc) you can use the R package optparse (inspired from Python):
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optparse/vignettes/optparse.pdf.

At least this how I understand your question, because I found this post when looking for an equivalent of the bash getopt, or perl Getopt, or python argparse and optparse.

Answer (score 1):

I just put together a nice data structure and chain of processing to generate this switching behaviour, no libraries needed. I'm sure it will have been implemented numerous times over, and came across this thread looking for examples - thought I'd chip in.

I didn't even particularly need flags (the only flag here is a debug mode, creating a variable which I check for as a condition of starting a downstream function `if (!exists(debug.mode)) {...} else {print(variables)})`. The flag checking `lapply` statements below produce the same as:

```
if ("--debug" %in% args) debug.mode <- T
if ("-h" %in% args || "--help" %in% args)
```

where `args` is the variable read in from command line arguments (a character vector, equivalent to `c('--debug','--help')` when you supply these on for instance)

It's reusable for any other flag and you avoid all the repetition, and no libraries so no dependencies:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

flag.details <- list(
"debug" = list(
  def = "Print variables rather than executing function XYZ...",
  flag = "--debug",
  output = "debug.mode <- T"),
"help" = list(
  def = "Display flag definitions",
  flag = c("-h","--help"),
  output = "cat(help.prompt)") )

flag.conditions <- lapply(flag.details, function(x) {
  paste0(paste0('"',x$flag,'"'), sep = " %in% args", collapse = " || ")
})
flag.truth.table <- unlist(lapply(flag.conditions, function(x) {
  if (eval(parse(text = x))) {
    return(T)
  } else return(F)
}))

help.prompts <- lapply(names(flag.truth.table), function(x){
# joins 2-space-separatated flags with a tab-space to the flag description
  paste0(c(paste0(flag.details[x][[1]][['flag']], collapse="  "),
  flag.details[x][[1]][['def']]), collapse="\t")
} )

help.prompt <- paste(c(unlist(help.prompts),''),collapse="\n\n")

# The following lines handle the flags, running the corresponding 'output' entry in flag.details for any supplied
flag.output <- unlist(lapply(names(flag.truth.table), function(x){
  if (flag.truth.table[x]) return(flag.details[x][[1]][['output']])
}))
eval(parse(text = flag.output))
```

Note that in `flag.details` here the commands are stored as strings, then evaluated with `eval(parse(text = '...'))`. Optparse is obviously desirable for any serious script, but minimal-functionality code is good too sometimes.

Sample output:

```
$ Rscript check_mail.Rscript --help
--debug Print  variables rather than executing function XYZ...

-h  --help  Display flag definitions
```