# Parsing command line arguments in R scripts

Tags: parsing, r, command-line-arguments

Is there any convenient way to automatically parse command line arguments passed to R scripts?

Something like perl's `Getopt::Long`?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There are three packages on CRAN:

- [getopt](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/getopt/index.html): C-like getopt behavior
- [optparse](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optparse/index.html): a command line parser inspired by Python's *optparse* library
- [argparse](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/argparse/index.html): a command line optional and positional argument parser (inspired by Python's *argparse* library). This package requires that a Python interpreter be installed with the `argparse` and `json` (or `simplejson`) modules.

**Update**:

- [docopt](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/docopt/index.html): lets you define a command line interface by just giving it a description in the specific format. It is a port a [docopt.py](https://github.com/docopt/docopt).
- [argparser](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/argparser/index.html): cross-platform command-line argument parser written purely in R with no external dependencies. This package is useful with the Rscript front-end and facilitates turning an R script into an executable script.
- [minimist](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/minimist/index.html): A binding to the minimist JavaScript library. This module implements the guts of optimist's argument parser without all the fanciful decoration (no external dependencies)
- [optigrab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optigrab/index.html): parse options from the command-line using a simple, clean syntax. It requires little or no specification and supports short and long options, GNU-, Java- or Microsoft- style syntaxes, verb commands and more.

Comment: For some reason, `argparse` actually *requires* Python. Made me try `optparse` first...

Comment: unsolicited advice - as tempting as it is to use the outstanding python argparse package from within R, the cross-language dependency just makes your R script that much more complex and fragile.  Don't do it.  Use one of the pure-R options described above.

Comment: Also, it seems like using the argparse library for R really slows down your script.

Comment: `optigrab` has a [bug][https://github.com/decisionpatterns/optigrab/issues/1] in `opt_help()` which hasn't been resolved in >4 years despite a PR being provided.  It makes it pretty unusable for the intended purpose.

Answer (score 37):

The simplest way is to use commandArgs().  Example - save the code below as "options.R":

```
options <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
options
```

Run using "Rscript options.R x y z".  Result:

```
[1] "x" "y" "z"
```

*i.e.* a list of 3 elements, one per argument.

Comment: This is not similar to `getopt` option parsing.

Comment: Please note I answered this almost 7 years ago; there's sure to be a better way now :)

Comment: `commandArgs(TRUE)` is perfectly fine even today. As long as the arguments are sufficiently simple, there is no need for additional dependency.

Answer (score 12):

Just to complement the Rscript answer:

```
edd@max:~$ r -e 'print(argv)' flim flam flom
[1] "flim" "flam" "flom"
edd@max:~$
```

We just use `argv` in [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html). I had good luck with [getopt](http://cran.r-project.org/package=getopt), the older of the two available parsing packages.

Answer (score 6):

May I introduce `ArgumentParser` in [Xmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Xmisc/index.html) package? It is a command line parser inspired by Python's `argparse` but it is Python-free.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Xmisc/vignettes/Xmisc-ArgumentParser.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [getopt long](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html) is in the `--parameter=argument` format like so

```sh
rscript script.R --parameter1=argument1 --parameter2=argument2
```

It can be parsed by just using basic string packages.

### Example

#### `cli.r`

```
library(pracma)
library(stringr)
run.arguments <- commandArgs(TRUE)
valid.run.parameters <- c( "universe", "character", "ability" )
for ( i in 1:length( run.arguments ) ) {
    if ( strcmpi( substr( run.arguments[i], 1, 2 ), "--" ) & grepl( "=", run.arguments[i], fixed = TRUE) ) {
        key.pair <- str_split( run.arguments[i], "=", simplify=TRUE )
        run.parameter <- gsub( "--", "", key.pair[1] )
        run.argument <- key.pair[2]
        if ( run.parameter %in% valid.run.parameters ) {

            # DO YOUR MAGIC HERE! Here is an example...
            cat( run.parameter, "\n" )
            cat( run.argument,  "\n\n" )

        }
    }
}
```

The above script was written for brevity. See the [more compelling version](https://gist.github.com/abelcallejo/f557a7d4ce7e37bbe5306dae864d0f0f#command-line).

#### Usage

```sh
rscript cli.R --universe=MCU --character="Wade Wilson"
```

**Output**

```
universe
MCU

character
Wade Wilson
```