# docopt - require specific data type for each arg

Tags: python, r, docopt

I generally use argparse in Python and docopt in R. One of the features I miss from argparse that I have not yet figured out in docopt is the ability to specify the required data type for each argument. For example, in argparse I would require an integer input using

```
parser.add_argument("square", help="display a square of a given number",
                type=int)
```

In docopt / R, I can't find anything in the documentation about requiring a specific data type.

```
-s <square>, --square=<square>   display a square of a given number #additional option to require integer input?
```

There's a closed [issue](https://github.com/docopt/docopt/issues/8) on the Python version of docopt GitHub repo that seems to indicate that this is not a part of base docopt and offers a solution for Python, but this isn't directly applicable to R. Can anyone offer any suggestions / more elegant way to validate argument inputs using docopt in R?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is elegant enough as it involves setting defaults and then using `utils::type.convert` determine the class/typeof

```
"Usage: my_program.R [-hson FILE] [--quiet | --verbose] [INPUT ...]

-h --help        show this 
-s --sorted      sorted output
--coefficient=K  [default: 2.95] The K coefficient 
--numSim=K       [default: 200] number of simulations 
--output=FILE    [default: test.txt] Output file 
--directory=DIR  [default: ./] Some directory 
-o FILE          specify output file [default: ./test.txt]
--quiet          print less text
--verbose        print more text" -> doc
opts <- docopt(doc, "-s --quiet")
str(opts)

newopts <- lapply(opts, function(x) utils::type.convert(as.character(x),as.is=T))
(definedClasses <- unlist(lapply(newopts, typeof)))
```

When you are running the program, you can test the inputs against this `definedClasses`.

You might also want to check out the `getopt` and `optparse`/`argparse` packages and also this SO post [Parsing command line arguments in R scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433603/parsing-command-line-arguments-in-r-scripts)

References:

http://docopt.org

http://rgrannell1.github.io/blog/2014/08/04/command-line-interfaces-in-r

http://docopt.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.0/

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting information. I may play around with this approach some in the future. I ended up using the testthat package to write tests to check that user input conformed to expectations.

Answer (score -2):

I'm a little curious why you don't use `docopt` with python or why you don't you use `argparse` (or `optparse`) in R?

In case you were wondering this is how to do your requested feature with the `optparse` R package:

```
> library("optparse")
> parser = OptionParser()
> parser = add_option(parser, c("-s", "--square"), 
+    type="integer", 
+    help="display a square of a given number")
> typeof(parse_args(parser, "--square=5")$square)
[1] "integer"
```

How to do this with the `argparse` package (this latter one has a python dependency):

```
> parser = argparse::ArgumentParser()
> parser$add_argument("-s", "--square", 
+    type="integer",
+    help="display a square of a given number")
> typeof(parser$parse_args("--square=5")$square)
[1] "integer"
```