# passing ellipsis (dotdotdot) argument to function command line in R

Tags: r, arguments, ellipsis

I have a function which takes multiple csv files and processes them into an excel file.

```
#review.R

review <- function(... ,savename) {
 somecodes
}
```

and I have these files in my folder:

```
fileA.csv
fileB.csv
fileC.csv
fileD.csv
...
```

and this is how I run it:

```
review("fileA","fileB","fileC","fileD", savename="analysis")
```

And then it processes and outputs "analysis.xlsx"

I have no problem running it in RStudio, but I really would like to run my script in cmd line like this:

```
rscript.exe f_wrapper.r "fileA" "fileB" "fileC" "fileD" savename="analysis"
```

This is my f_wrapper.R

```
#f_wrapper.R
#this script doesn't work at all

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
obj <- list(...)


source("my_R_folder/review.R")

review(obj)
```

I googled all over but all I could find was passing fixed arguments like a,b,c but I am trying to pass a,b,c,d,e .... and more arguments to my function.

Please help.

Comment: Put the args in a list, and use `do.call(review, thelist)`.

Comment: You'll need to parse `args` to make the difference between `savename` and the other arguments. Did you have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433603/parsing-command-line-arguments-in-r-scripts ?