# Is there a way to pass named arguments into an Rscript using a bash command?

Tags: r, bash

For example, if my bash command is:

```
Rscript $wd/scripts/test.R celFiles=$celFiles
```

I would like to be able to access this argument in R as such:

```
args=commandArgs(trailingOnly=T)
args['celFiles']
```

Sadly, this produces an "NA", while `args[1]` seems to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/q/3433603/4550695

Comment: There are dedicated packages for this task, see linked post, let us know if they do not work for you.

Comment: Go with `docopt` which is a little newer than the linked post (though it is mentioned) and portable in that the spec is implemented for several languages -- you learn multiple tools at once. Many usage examples for `docopt` among my `littler` examples here:  https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/tree/master/inst/examples