# Running an R file with arguments from a bash script

Tags: bash, r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I read command line parameters from an R script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script)

I've got a R script for which I'd like to be able to supply several command-line parameters (rather than hardcode parameter values in the code itself). The script runs on linux.

I can't find out how how to read the R.script on the command line Bash.

sh file

```
cd `dirname $0`
/usr/lib64/R/bin/R --vanilla --slave "--args input='$1' input2='$2' output='$3'"  file=/home/lvijfhuizen/galaxy_dist/tools/lisanne/partone.R  $3.txt
```

R file

```
args <- commandArgs()
file <- read.csv(args[8],head=TRUE,sep="\t")   
annfile <- read.csv(args[9],head=TRUE,sep="\t")
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+script+command+line+parameters  It's not the best search function at hand, but it does work sometimes...

Answer (score 5):

To source a R script from the command line, you can pipe it into R with `<`.

For example, if I create the following `test.sh` bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash

rfile=$1
shift
R --vanilla --slave --args $* < $rfile
exit 0
```

where `test.R` is the following R script in the same directory :

```
print(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE))
```

Then running the script with `test.R` as first argument and possibly others will give something like this :

```
$ ./test.sh test.R foo bar 1 2 3
[1] "foo" "bar" "1"   "2"   "3"
```

**EDIT :** another way, maybe cleaner, is to use the dedicated `Rscript` command. Then you can put directly in your bash script something like :

```
rfile=$1
shift
Rscript $rfile $*
```

which should give the same results.