# What 1-2 letter object names conflict with existing R objects?

Tags: r, naming-conventions

To make my code more readable, I like to avoid names of objects that already exist when creating new objects. Because of the package-based nature of R, and because functions are first-class objects, it can be easy to overwrite common functions that are not in base R (since a common package might use a short function name but without knowing what package to load there is no way to check for it).  Objects such as the built-in logicals T and F also cause trouble.

Some examples that come to mind are:

**One letter**

- c
- t
- T/F
- J

**Two letters**

- df

A better solution might be to avoid using short names altogether in favor of more descriptive ones, and I generally try to do that as a matter of habit.  Yet "df" for a function which manipulates a generic data.frame is plenty descriptive and a longer name adds little, so short names have their uses.  In addition, for SO questions where the larger context isn't necessarily known, coming up with descriptive names is well-nigh impossible.

**What other one- and two-letter variable names conflict with existing R objects?**  Which among those are sufficiently common that they should be avoided?  If they are not in `base`, please list the package as well.  The best answers will involve at least some code; please provide it if used.

Note that I am not asking whether or not overwriting functions that already exist is advisable or not.  That question is addressed on SO already:

[In R, what exactly is the problem with having variables with the same name as base R functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6135868/602276)

For visualizations of some answers here, see this question on CV:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13999/visualizing-2-letter-combinations

Comment: The reasons are not as self-evident as you may think.  Have a look at this question that probes the possible problems: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6135868/602276  In short, having a variable name with the same name as an existing function is generally not a problem, other than it could be confusing.

Comment: That's an awesome question/answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I think your edit makes this question no longer fit with the [faq]

Comment: You can check if you have a potential issue after you have named your variables by using `conflicts(detail=TRUE)`

Comment: @David: I'm not seeing the conflict.  It's a specific question, with a well-defined best answer, about a specific problem I am facing.  I agree the "should be avoided" part seems subjective so I have reworded to make it clear that I am asking a well-defined q.

Comment: You are asking for lists, personal preferences, opinions.

Comment: @David: I'm asking for a single vector of 1-2 character function names, with code to produce it.  My own partial solution is entirely programmatic.

Comment: What about hidden variables, e.g. `.i` or `.ix`?  If such short hidden variables exist, I suppose these could be problematic, too.

Comment: @Iterator: Yes, but people are less likely to accidentally run across those.  Because...they're hidden ;-)

Comment: But it's not impossible, right?  ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`apropos` is ideal for this:

```
apropos("^[[:alpha:]]{1,2}$")
```

With no packages loaded, this returns:

```
 [1] "ar" "as" "by" "c"  "C"  "cm" "D"  "de" "df" "dt" "el" "F"  "gc" "gl"
[15] "I"  "if" "Im" "is" "lh" "lm" "ls" "pf" "pi" "pt" "q"  "qf" "qr" "qt"
[29] "Re" "rf" "rm" "rt" "sd" "t"  "T"  "ts" "vi"
```

The exact contents will depend upon the search list.  Try loading a few packages and re-running it if you care about conflicts with packages that you commonly use.

---

I loaded all the (>200) packages installed on my machine with this:

```
lapply(rownames(installed.packages()), require, character.only = TRUE)
```

And reran the call to `apropos`, wrapping it in `unique`, since there were a few duplicates.

```
one_or_two <- unique(apropos("^[[:alpha:]]{1,2}$"))
```

This returned:

```
  [1] "Ad" "am" "ar" "as" "bc" "bd" "bp" "br" "BR" "bs" "by" "c"  "C" 
 [14] "cc" "cd" "ch" "ci" "CJ" "ck" "Cl" "cm" "cn" "cq" "cs" "Cs" "cv"
 [27] "d"  "D"  "dc" "dd" "de" "df" "dg" "dn" "do" "ds" "dt" "e"  "E" 
 [40] "el" "ES" "F"  "FF" "fn" "gc" "gl" "go" "H"  "Hi" "hm" "I"  "ic"
 [53] "id" "ID" "if" "IJ" "Im" "In" "ip" "is" "J"  "lh" "ll" "lm" "lo"
 [66] "Lo" "ls" "lu" "m"  "MH" "mn" "ms" "N"  "nc" "nd" "nn" "ns" "on"
 [79] "Op" "P"  "pa" "pf" "pi" "Pi" "pm" "pp" "ps" "pt" "q"  "qf" "qq"
 [92] "qr" "qt" "r"  "Re" "rf" "rk" "rl" "rm" "rt" "s"  "sc" "sd" "SJ"
[105] "sn" "sp" "ss" "t"  "T"  "te" "tr" "ts" "tt" "tz" "ug" "UG" "UN"
[118] "V"  "VA" "Vd" "vi" "Vo" "w"  "W"  "y"
```

You can see where they came from with

```
lapply(one_or_two, find)
```

Comment: @Richie: You have a lot more packages installed than I do!  I only get to 63 using the same apropos....

Comment: @gsk: Yeah.  It's a combination of a really old machine, and installing random packages to answer questions on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Been thinking about this more.  Here's a list of one-letter object names in base R:

```
> var.names <- c(letters,LETTERS)
> var.names[sapply(var.names,exists)]
[1] "c" "q" "t" "C" "D" "F" "I" "T" "X"
```

And one- and two-letter object names in base R:

```
one.letter.names <- c(letters,LETTERS)

N <- length(one.letter.names)


first <- rep(one.letter.names,N)
second <- rep(one.letter.names,each=N)

two.letter.names <- paste(first,second,sep="")

var.names <- c(one.letter.names,two.letter.names)

> var.names[sapply(var.names,exists)]
[1] "c"  "d"  "q"  "t"  "C"  "D"  "F"  "I"  "J"  "N"  "T"  "X"  "bc" "gc"
[15] "id" "sd" "de" "Re" "df" "if" "pf" "qf" "rf" "lh" "pi" "vi" "el" "gl"
[29] "ll" "cm" "lm" "rm" "Im" "sp" "qq" "ar" "qr" "tr" "as" "bs" "is" "ls"
[43] "ns" "ps" "ts" "dt" "pt" "qt" "rt" "tt" "by" "VA" "UN"
```

That's a much bigger list than I initially suspected, although I would never think of naming a variable "if", so to a certain degree it makes sense.

Still doesn't capture object names not in base, or give any sense of which functions are best avoided.  I think a better answer would either use expert opinion to figure out which functions are important (e.g. using `c` is probably worse than using `qf`) or use a data mining approach on a bunch of R code to see what short-named functions get used the most.

Comment: `if` is a reserved word so it is impossible to redefine.  Try it:  `if <- 1`  results in `Error: unexpected assignment in "if <-"`

Comment: Good point.  `by` `as` `is` `ts` and others can still be redefined though.  The ones ending in "s" are particularly tempting, since when I use loops (less and less these days), I tend to call the vector holding the values e.g. `ts` for t (plural), and the loop is `for(t in ts)`.

Comment: Note you can use assign to name something almost anything. Try assign("i<!{",99)

Comment: @Spacedman: Away, ye devil!  Thy temptation o'erwhelms me!  And to use it you still have to enclose in back-ticks.

Comment: If this is for package writing, it's usually easier to provide a nomenclature for your functions. Let's say your package is called "gsk". Your functions could be gsk.x, gsk_y, gskX and so one. Other coders do this already. Take plyr for example, d_ply, ddply, dlply. The nomenclature also helps people remember semantics too.

Comment: if you are going to call your package 'foo' and all your functions are named 'foo-this' and 'foo-that', you've just re-implemented namespaces. You may as well call them 'this' and 'that' and access them via 'foo:::this' and 'foo:::that'.

Comment: @Andrie: Try out `assign("if",3)`  :)  Of course that only modifies "if" not `if`.  This is better: `assign("if",function(...){print("Inconceivable!")})`

Comment: You had me there for a minute.   Nice.

Comment: I like my computer: `could not find function "humble"`  ;-)

Comment: @Andrie: But the revised one actually works!  Try it.  As far as I can tell, it will ignore the parameters and just prints "Inconceivable!"  (What can I say, I do not think **impossible** means what you think it means.  ;-))

Comment: `rep(Inf, assign(impossible, nothing))`

Comment: I wonder about characters other than letters.  This one is cute: `assign("?",function(...){print("No help for you!")})`  :)

Comment: You can name a variable "if" using `\`if\` <- 3` but it'll only return the value if you use `\`if\``