# Generating multiple datasets and applying function and output multiple dataset

Tags: r

Here is my problem, just hard for me...

I want to generate multiple datasets, then apply a function to these datasets and output corresponding output in single or multiple dataset (whatever possible)...

My example, although I need to generate a large number of variables and datasets

```
seed <- round(runif(10)*1000000)

datagen <- function(x){
set.seed(x)
var <- rep(1:3, c(rep(3, 3)))
yvar <- rnorm(length(var), 50, 10)
matrix <- matrix(sample(1:10, c(10*length(var)), replace = TRUE), ncol = 10)
mydata <- data.frame(var, yvar, matrix)
}

gdt <- lapply (seed,  datagen) 

# resulting list (I believe is correct term) has 10 dataframes: 
# gdt[1] .......to gdt[10]

# my function, this will perform anova in every component data frames and 
#output probability coefficients...  
anovp <- function(x){
          ind <- 3:ncol(x) 
          out <- lm(gdt[x]$yvar ~ gdt[x][, ind[ind]])
          pval <- out$coefficients[,4][2]
          pval <- do.call(rbind,pval) 
         }

plist <- lapply (gdt,  anovp) 

Error in gdt[x] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

This is not working, I tried different options. But could not figure out...finally decided to bother experts, sorry for that...

My questions are:

(1) Is this possible to handle such situation in this way or there are other alternatives to handle such multiple datasets created?

(2)  If this is right way, how can I do it?

Thank you for attention and I will appreciate your help...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the basic idea right, in that you should create a list of data frames and then use `lapply` to apply the function to each element of the list.  Unfortunately, there are several oddities in your code.

There is no point in randomly generating a seed, then setting it.  You only need to use `set.seed` in order to make random numbers reproducible.  Cut the lines

```
seed <- round(runif(10)*1000000)
```

and maybe

```
set.seed(x)
```

---

`rep(1:3, c(rep(3, 3)))` is the same as `rep(1:3, each = 3)`.

---

Don't call your variables `var` or `matrix`, <del>since they will mask the names of those functions.</del> since it's confusing.

---

`3:ncol(x)` is dangerous.  If `x` has less than 3 columns it doesn't do what you think it does.

---

... and now, the problem you actually wanted solving.

The problem is in the line `out <- lm(gdt[x]$yvar ~ gdt[x][, ind[ind]])`.

`lapply` passes data frames into `anovp`, not indicies, so `x` is a data frame in `gdt[x]`.  Which throws an error.

---

One more thing.  While you are rewriting that line, note that `lm` takes a data argument, so you don't need to do things like `gdt$some_column`; you can just reference `some_column` directly.

---

EDIT: Further advice.

You appear to always use the formula `yvar ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10`.  Since its the same each time, create it before your call to `lapply`.

```
independent_vars <- paste(colnames(gdt[[1]])[-1:-2], collapse = " + ")
model_formula <- formula(paste("yvar", independent_vars, sep = " ~ "))
```

I probably wouldn't bother with the `anovp` function.  Just do

```
models <- lapply(gdt, function(data) lm(model_formula, data))
```

Then include a further call to `lapply` to play with the coefficients if necessary.  The next line replicates your `anovp` code, but won't work because `model$coefficients` is a vector (so the dimensions aren't right).  Adjust to retrieve the bit you actualy want.

```
coeffs <- lapply(models, function(model) do.call(rbind, model$coefficients[,4][2]))
```

Comment: Good advice except for the rationale for not using names of functions. Names of objects are kept in a separate list. Creating an object named "var" will not mask the `var` function, but it's still not a good idea because the human brain is not as carefully organized.

Comment: @DWin: True, R is reasonable at figuring out whether to use a variable or a function, but the there are some ambiguous cases where masking does occur.  For example, type `var` at the command prompt, and R prints the function definition.  Now define `var <- 1:5` and repeat.  This time the varaible is printed.

Comment: @RichieCotton Nice answer, but I agree with @DWin about masking - this is not an issue.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6135868/602276 for an explanation.  The code `x <- 1:5; var(x); var <- "a"; var; var(x)` will do everything as you expect, despite the fact that there is a new var called `var`.

Comment: thank you so much...I tried the following - still unsuccessful..still I am not grasping what you mean...                 "anovp <- function(x){
          ind <- 3:ncol(x)
          out <- lm(x[,3] ~ x[, ind])
          pval <- out$coefficients[,4][2]
          pval <- do.call(rbind,pval)
         }