# Extracting characters from entries in a vector in R

Tags: r, extract

There are functions in Excel called `left`, `right`, and `mid`, where you can extract part of the entry from a cell.  For example, `=left(A1, 3)`, would return the 3 left most characters in cell A1, and `=mid(A1, 3, 4)` would start with the the third character in cell A1 and give you characters number 3 - 6.  Are there similar functions in R or similarly straightforward ways to do this?

As a simplified sample problem I would like to take a vector

```
sample<-c("TRIBAL","TRISTO", "RHOSTO", "EUGFRI", "BYRRAT")
```

and create 3 new vectors that contain the first 3 characters in each entry, the middle 2 characters in each entry, and the last 4 characters in each entry.

A slightly more complicated question that Excel doesn't have a function for (that I know of) would be how to create a new vector with the 1st, 3rd, and 5th characters from each entry.

Comment: Just FYI, it's good practice to not name your objects with the names of such important functions as `sample` (or `c`, or `df` and so on) from base R.

Comment: @mrdwab Good comment, but it really does't matter all that much.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6135868/602276

Comment: @Andrie, great set of answers in that linked question (nice question too). For me, the main problem that comes to mind is readability and debugging, or even looking at some code I wrote a year ago; but, if the code is properly documented or commented in the first place, that would be *less* of a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for the function `substr` or its close relative `substring`:

The leading characters are straight-forward:

```
substr(sample, 1, 3)
[1] "TRI" "TRI" "RHO" "EUG" "BYR"
```

So is extracting some characters at a defined position:

```
substr(sample, 2, 3)
[1] "RI" "RI" "HO" "UG" "YR"
```

To get the trailing characters, you have two options:

```
substr(sample, nchar(sample)-3, nchar(sample))
[1] "IBAL" "ISTO" "OSTO" "GFRI" "RRAT"

substring(sample, nchar(sample)-3)
[1] "IBAL" "ISTO" "OSTO" "GFRI" "RRAT"
```

---

And your final "complicated" question:

```
characters <- function(x, pos){
  sapply(x, function(x)
    paste(sapply(pos, function(i)substr(x, i, i)), collapse=""))
}
characters(sample, c(1,3,5))
TRIBAL TRISTO RHOSTO EUGFRI BYRRAT 
 "TIA"  "TIT"  "ROT"  "EGR"  "BRA"
```

Comment: Seeing these `sample`s in here is making me cringe!

Comment: @mrdwab Although I agree with you, given more than a 1000 functions in base R, it's sometimes hard to not inadvertently use a function name for a variable. Keep in mind that to R that doesn't matter, since you're not redefining the `sample()` function.