# Sine curve fit using lm and nls in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I am a beginner in curve fitting and several posts on Stackoverflow really helped me.

I tried to fit a sine curve to my data using `lm` and `nls` but both methods show a strange fit as shown below. Could anyone point out where I went wrong. I would suspect something to do with time but could not get it right. My data can be accessed from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzzExM8ZYZwxMWNpeHV0bGFBMUk/edit?usp=sharing).
[image: plot]

```
data <- read.table(file="900days.txt", header=TRUE, sep="")
time<-data$time
temperature<-data$temperature

#lm fitting
xc<-cos(2*pi*time/366)
xs<-sin(2*pi*time/366)
fit.lm<-lm(temperature~xc+xs)
summary(fit.lm)
plot(temp~time, data=data, xlim=c(1, 900))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(fit.lm$fitted, type="l", col="red", xlim=c(1, 900), pch=19, ann=FALSE, xaxt="n",
yaxt="n")

#nls fitting
fit.nls<-nls(temp~C+alpha*sin(W*time+phi),
   start=list(C=27.63415, alpha=27.886, W=0.0652, phi=14.9286))
summary(fit.nls)
plot(fit.nls$fitted, type="l", col="red", xlim=c(1, 900), pch=19, ann=FALSE, xaxt="n", 
axt="n")
```

Comment: `fit.lm` is of class "lm" , so there's a plot method for it. `plot(fit.lm, type.....)` may be more what you want.

Comment: What is the significance/ where is the "366" coming from in the formula 2*pi*time/366 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because the `NA` values are removed from the data to be fit (and your data has quite a few of them); hence, when you plot `fit.lm$fitted` the plot method is interpreting the index of that series as the 'x' values to plot it against.

Try this [note how I've changed variable names to prevent conflicts with the functions `time` and `data` (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135868/in-r-what-exactly-is-the-problem-with-having-variables-with-the-same-name-as-ba) post)]:

```
Data <- read.table(file="900days.txt", header=TRUE, sep="")
Time <- Data$time 
temperature <- Data$temperature

xc<-cos(2*pi*Time/366)
xs<-sin(2*pi*Time/366)
fit.lm <- lm(temperature~xc+xs)

# access the fitted series (for plotting)
fit <- fitted(fit.lm)  

# find predictions for original time series
pred <- predict(fit.lm, newdata=data.frame(Time=Time))    

plot(temperature ~ Time, data= Data, xlim=c(1, 900))
lines(fit, col="red")
lines(Time, pred, col="blue")
```

This gives me:

[image]

Which is probably what you were hoping for.

Comment: I just wondering how to refine so that the curve actually fit the maximum temperature values.

Comment: @Eddie I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks again @Andy Barbour, I was hoping that the blue curve is running through some of the maximum values(e.g at 29.5 degree Celcius at the first peak). At the moment, the highest peak for the predicition(blue curve) is somewhere around 28.8 degree Celcius. I am not sure how to refine this in lm. For nls, I think I can achieve that by changing my initial parameters value(which is also a tricky part). :)

Comment: Then I think you'd want to use the `'weights'` field; but, you may wish to ask over at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This only works when one period = 1 unit of t, is it possible to adjust it if one period is not 1 unit of t. Or is there another way to do this? I'm trying to fir a curve to this data: `t<-c(1,16,32,46,60,75,91,105, 121,  136, 152, 166, 182, 197, 213, 228, 244, 258, 274,289,  305, 319, 335, 350)
y<-c(0.07675029,0.06820963,0.05715293,0.05327944,0.05299214,0.05741750,0.07288807,0.11433698,0.26188523,0.35214251,0.46357182,0.55140384,0.59743720,0.60758298,0.59527024,0.55041092,0.46916025,0.39096330,0.27733599,0.20236358,0.12148088,0.08689101,0.08020721,0.07943709)`

Answer (score 4):

How about choosing an X and an Y while doing your line plot instead of just choosing the Y.

```
plot(time,predict(fit.nls),type="l", col="red", xlim=c(1, 900), pch=19, ann=FALSE, xaxt="n",
yaxt="n")
```

Also both `lm` and `nls` just give you the fitted points. So you must estimate the rest of the points in order to make a curve, a line plot. Since you are with `nls` and `lm`, perhaps the function `predict` maybe useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this might help - I get a similar fit using sine only:

```
y = amplitude * sin(pi * (x - center) / width) + Offset

amplitude =  2.0009690806953033E+00
center = -2.5813588834888215E+01
width =  1.8077550471975817E+02
Offset =  2.6872265116104828E+01

Fitting target of lowest sum of squared absolute error = 3.6755174406241423E+01

Degrees of freedom (error): 90
Degrees of freedom (regression): 3
Chi-squared: 36.7551744062
R-squared: 0.816419142696
R-squared adjusted: 0.810299780786
Model F-statistic: 133.415731033
Model F-statistic p-value: 1.11022302463e-16
Model log-likelihood: -89.2464811027
AIC: 1.98396768304
BIC: 2.09219299292
Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE): 0.625309918107

amplitude = 2.0009690806953033E+00
       std err squared: 1.03828E-02
       t-stat: 1.96374E+01
       p-stat: 0.00000E+00
       95% confidence intervals: [1.79853E+00, 2.20340E+00]
center = -2.5813588834888215E+01
       std err squared: 2.98349E+01
       t-stat: -4.72592E+00
       p-stat: 8.41245E-06
       95% confidence intervals: [-3.66651E+01, -1.49621E+01]
width = 1.8077550471975817E+02
       std err squared: 3.54835E+00
       t-stat: 9.59680E+01
       p-stat: 0.00000E+00
       95% confidence intervals: [1.77033E+02, 1.84518E+02]
Offset = 2.6872265116104828E+01
       std err squared: 5.15458E-03
       t-stat: 3.74289E+02
       p-stat: 0.00000E+00
       95% confidence intervals: [2.67296E+01, 2.70149E+01]

Coefficient Covariance Matrix
[ 0.02542366 0.01786683 -0.05016085 -0.00652111]
[ 1.78668314e-02 7.30548346e+01 -2.18160818e+01 1.24965136e-01]
[ -5.01608451e-02 -2.18160818e+01 8.68860810e+00 -1.27401806e-02]
[-0.00652111 0.12496514 -0.01274018 0.0126217 ]
```

James Phillips
zunzun@zunzun.com

Comment: Thanks @James Phillips. Thats true. You might want to check this post  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60500/how-to-find-a-good-fit-for-semi-sinusoidal-model-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could have eliminated the NAs from your data after reading it in:

```
data <- subset(data, !is.na(temperature))
```

Then, when plotting, you could set the x-axis to the time points from the reduced data set:

```
plot(temp~time, data=data, xlim=c(1, 900))
lines(x=time, y=fit.lm$fitted, col="red")
```

This curve won't be as smooth as the one produced by @andy-barbour but it will work in a pinch.