# Model tidal river water level in space and time [revised]

Tags: r, curve-fitting, modeling, waveform, gam

I decided to revise my question to make it more clear [25.03.2021]:

I have a dataset of measured water levels over one year for 12 measuring stations along a tidal river. Hereby each measuring station has a river kilometre value that works as a variable representing space. The water level shows a periodic/sinusoidal pattern over time and slightly also over space. And now I need to model water levels over time and space.

Since this dataset is too big and since I have no permission to share, I simulated some data according to a wave function ψ(x,t) = Ao sin[ωt - kx + φo]. The [real data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNXaQ.png) is a bit more complicated but both methods I tried (nlsLM and GAM) do not work for both real and simulated data. Therefore, simulated data is enough to demonstrate my problem.

nlsLM does only work then I nearly perfectly predefine all model parameters, if they deviate only slightly this method completely fails [as can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q7FD.png).

GAM works pretty good for time and space components separately but not then combined [as can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaiYN.png).

Maybe somebody knows what I did wrong with these methods or are other methods are better suited?

```
###### Simulate data (similar to original dataset but less complicated) ######

### Create Long-Table
stations <- seq(0,350,30)
start_time <- "2020-01-01 00:00:00"
end_time <- "2020-01-31 00:00:00"
time_interval <- "30 mins"
time_vector <- seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct(start_time), 
                          to = as.POSIXct(end_time), 
                          by = time_interval)
df <- data.frame(time = rep(time_vector, times = length(stations)), 
                 place = rep(stations, each=length(time_vector)),
                 timediff = as.numeric(difftime(rep(time_vector, times = length(stations)),
                                                as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00:00"), 
                                                units = "mins")))

### Parameter according to a wave function
A0 <- 200
k0 <- 0.023
w0 <- 0.005 
phi0 <- 10

### Simulate water level values
df$level <- A0*sin(k0*df$place + w0*df$timediff + phi0)

### Plot simulated data
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(level~timediff, data = df[df$place==30,], type = "l",
     main="Water level over time")
plot(level~place, data = df[df$timediff==30,], type = "l",
     main="Water level over space")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))



###### Try to estimate model function parameters using nlsLM ######

### Modelling using nlsLM
library(minpack.lm)
nlsmod <- nlsLM(level ~ A*sin(k*df$place + w*df$timediff + phi), data = df, 
                start=c(A = 200, k = 0.023, w = 0.001, phi = 10),
                lower=c(A = 100, k = 0.001, w = 0.005, phi = 0),
                upper=c(A = 1000, k = 0.01, w = 0.1, phi = 1000),
                control=nls.lm.control(maxiter=1000))
# defining an area to search for parameters did not worked despite the real values are included
nlsmod <- nlsLM(level ~ A*sin(k*df$place + w*df$timediff + phi), data = df, 
                start=c(A = 200, k = 0.023, w = 0.005, phi = 10),
                control=nls.lm.control(maxiter=1000))
# defining exactly the real model values worked but this makes no sense since I would like 
# to estimate them
nlsmod <- nlsLM(level ~ A*sin(k*df$place + w*df$timediff + phi), data = df, 
                start=c(A = 150, k = 0.023, w = 0.001, phi = 10),
                control=nls.lm.control(maxiter=1000))
# then changing just two values slightly the nlsLM (and nls) function does not work anymore
summary(nlsmod)
nlsmod

### Create new dataset
df.new = data.frame(timediff = df$timediff, place = df$place)
df.new$pred <- predict(nlsmod, df.new)

### Plot simulated and predicted data
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(level~timediff, data = df[df$place==30,], type = "l")
lines(pred~timediff, data = df.new[df.new$place==30,], type = "l", col = "red")
plot(level~place, data = df[df$timediff==0,], type = "l")
lines(pred~place, data = df.new[df.new$timediff==0,], type = "l", col = "red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))



###### Modeling using GAM ######

### Create one time and one space dataset for testing fit seperately
df.time <- df[df$place==30,]
df.place <- df[df$timediff==0,]

### Load package
library(mgcv)

### Test modeling space
plot(level ~  place, data = df.place, type = "p")
bam_mod <- bam(level ~  s(place), data = df.place)
plot(bam_mod)
df.new = data.frame(place = df.place$place)
df.new$pred <- predict(bam_mod, df.new)
plot(level~place, data = df.place, type = "p")
lines(pred~place, data = df.new, type = "p", col = "red")
# works well

### Test modeling time
plot(level ~  timediff, data = df.time, type = "l")
bam_mod <- bam(level ~  s(timediff, k=400, bs="cc"), data = df.time, discrete=TRUE, nthreads=10)
plot(bam_mod)
df.new = data.frame(timediff = df.time$timediff)
df.new$pred <- predict(bam_mod, df.new)
plot(level~timediff, data = df.time, type = "l")
lines(pred~timediff, data = df.new, type = "l", col = "red")
# works well

### Test modeling place and time
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(level~timediff, data = df[df$place==30,], type = "l")#, xlim=c(0,5000))
plot(level~place, data = df[df$timediff==0,], type = "l")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
bam_mod <- bam(level ~ s(place, k = 7, bs="cc") +
                       s(timediff, k=400, bs="cc") + 
                       s(timediff, place, k=400) +
                       place + 
                       timediff, 
                       data = df)#, discrete=TRUE, nthreads=10)
# takes a while but did not work
bam_mod <- bam(level ~ s(place, k = 7, bs="cc") + s(timediff, k=400, bs="cc"), data = df, discrete=TRUE, nthreads=10)
# faster but also did not work
plot(bam_mod)

### Create new dataset
df.new = data.frame(timediff = df$timediff, place = df$place)
df.new$pred <- predict(bam_mod, df.new)

### Plot simulated and predicted data
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(level~timediff, data = df[df$place==30,], type = "l")#, xlim=c(0,5000))
lines(pred~timediff, data = df.new[df.new$place==30,], type = "l", col = "red")
plot(level~place, data = df[df$timediff==0,], type = "l")
lines(pred~place, data = df.new[df.new$timediff==0,], type = "l", col = "red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may learn from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104680/sine-curve-fit-using-lm-and-nls-in-r)

I have used a simple linear model, implementing your own formula as follows:

```
stations <- seq(0,350,30)
start_time <- "2020-01-01 00:00:00"
end_time <- "2020-01-31 00:00:00"
time_interval <- "30 mins"
time_vector <- seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct(start_time), 
                                                    to = as.POSIXct(end_time), 
                                                    by = time_interval)
df <- data.frame(time = rep(time_vector, times = length(stations)), 
                                 place = rep(stations, each=length(time_vector)),
                                 timediff = as.numeric(difftime(rep(time_vector, times = length(stations)),
                                                                                             as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 00:00:00"), 
                                                                                             units = "mins")))

A <- 200
w <- 0.001 
phi <- 10
k <- 1
df$level <- A*sin(k*df$place + w*df$timediff + phi)


mod = lm( level ~ sin(k*place + w*timediff + phi), data = df )

plot(level~timediff, data = df[df$place==210,], type = "p", pch=16)
lines(fitted(mod)~timediff, data = df.new[df.new$place==30,],col='green')  

plot(level~place, data = df[df$timediff==0,], type = "p", pch=16)
lines(fitted(mod)~place, data = df.new[df.new$timediff==30,], type = "l", col = "red")
```

which will provide a 100% fit: [Plot of simulated and LM predicted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEz2x.png)

Comment: Hi Dario and welcome to SO. Do you have a question? If so, could you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately lm() does not estimate the model parameters but uses the parameters from simulating data. I should have given them different variable names. Thus, I corrected my initial post to make it more clear that I wanted to try to estimate model parameters. Nevertheless, thanks again!