# Merge two rows in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to merge rows in my `data.frame` based on `<NA>` value.

Here is my data frame.

```
new <- data.frame (
  Location = c(rep("Loc 1", 4), rep("Loc 2", 4)), 
  Place = c("Powder Springs_Original", "Bridge_Other County", "Airport", "County1", "City 4 - Duplicated", "South", "County2", "Formal place"), 
  Val1 = c(109, 123, NA, 117, 143, NA, 151, 142), 
  Val2 = c(102, 115, NA, 45, 135, NA, 144, 125), 
  Val3 = c(99, 112, NA, 26,  127, NA, 140, 132), 
  Val4 = c(90, 103, NA, 57, 125, NA, 135, 201))
```

I am expecting something like,

```
Location Place                      Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4
Loc 1    Powder Springs - Original  109   102   99  90
Loc 1    Bridge _ Other County      123   115  112  103
Loc 1    Airport County1            117   45    26  57
Loc 2    City 4 - Duplicated        143   135  127  125
Loc 2    South County2              151   144  140  135
Loc 2    Formal place               142   125  132  201
```

I want to remove the NA rows and merge data with the next row. Location for these values is same. Can someone please help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your NA values actually `NA` or are they strings like `"NA"`? There is a difference. e.g. `is.na("NA")` is `FALSE`

Comment: They are actually strings like "NA" . I did this in R. `is.na(new$Val1)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

Comment: Sorry @thelatemail. My fault. Those are indeed NA values. I was referring to the wrong `data.frame`. `is.na` gave `TRUE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help and support. After lot of trails, I got the below required output. (As suggested by @Robert Krzyzanowski, I renamed my `data.frame` to `Test`).

This is what I did. Please suggest, if anything weird is observed.

```
> new_DF <- subset(Test, is.na(Test$Val1))
> new_DF
  Location   Place Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4
3    Loc 1 Airport   NA   NA   NA   NA
6    Loc 2   South   NA   NA   NA   NA
> 
> row.names(new_DF)
[1] "3" "6"
> x.num <- as.numeric(row.names(new_DF))
> 
> Test$Place <- as.character(Test$Place)
> Test$Place[x.num + 1] <- paste(Test$Place[x.num], Test$Place[x.num + 1])
> Test <- Test[-x.num, ]
> Test
  Location                   Place Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4
1    Loc 1 Powder Springs_Original  109  102   99   90
2    Loc 1     Bridge_Other County  123  115  112  103
4    Loc 1         Airport County1  117   45   26   57
5    Loc 2     City 4 - Duplicated  143  135  127  125
7    Loc 2           South County2  151  144  140  135
8    Loc 2            Formal place  142  125  132  201
```

Once again, thank you all for your support and your time for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you shouldn't be using `new` as your variable name since it's a built-in R function. Second, you could do something like this:

```
# Find which rows are NA
na_rows <- which(apply(new, 1, function(x) all("NA" == (x[paste0('Val', 1:4)]))))
# Set correct place names
new$Place <- as.character(new$Place)
new$Place[na_rows + 1] <- paste(new$Place[na_rows], new$Place[na_rows + 1])
# Remove NAs
new <- new[-na_rows, ]
#   Location                   Place Val1 Val2 Val3 Val4
# 1    Loc 1 Powder Springs_Original  109  102   99   90
# 2    Loc 1     Bridge_Other County  123  115  112  103
# 4    Loc 1         Airport County1  117   45   26   57
# 5    Loc 2     City 4 - Duplicated  143  135  127  125
# 7    Loc 2           South County2  151  144  140  135
# 8    Loc 2            Formal place  142  125  132  201
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. This is really helpful. One quick question is, can I compare the same with a single column. when I tried something like this `cols <- new[,c(3)]

na_rows2 <- which(apply(new, 1, function(x) all("NA" == cols)))`, it gave me `integer(0)`. I want to know this, because one of the column names in my `data.frame` is `Price in dollars given`. As this is not a `Val1/2/3/4` I am interested to know how to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: A correction from my side. `NA's` are actually `NA` values, not `"NA"` strings. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I think your "First off" statement is unnecessary here. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135868/in-r-what-exactly-is-the-problem-with-having-variables-with-the-same-name-as-ba), for example.

Answer (score 0):

#### (edited as the initial answer was incomplete)

```
nu <- data.frame (
  Location = c(rep("Loc 1", 4), rep("Loc 2", 4)), 
  Place = c("Powder Springs_Original", "Bridge_Other County", "Airport", "County1", "City 4 - Duplicated", "South", "County2", "Formal place"), 
  Val1 = c(109, 123, NA, 117, 143, NA, 151, 142), 
  Val2 = c(102, 115, NA, 45, 135, NA, 144, 125), 
  Val3 = c(99, 112, NA, 26,  127, NA, 140, 132), 
  Val4 = c(90, 103, NA, 57, 125, NA, 135, 201), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# notice stringsAsFactors = FALSE
# if there was justice in the world, it should be FALSE by default in R
# in any case, nu$Place should be character rather than factor so in real data 
# you may need to do nu$Place <- as.character(nu$Place)

ic <- which(!complete.cases(nu))
nu$Place[ic-1] <- paste(nu$Place[ic-1], nu$Place[ic])
nu <- nu[-ic,]
```

Does this do what you need?

Comment: Hi @lebatsnok. It gave me the places where `NA's` are present. I would like to merge the values other than `NA's`. I edited my question above. could you please look into that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @lebatsnok for your reply. That was helpful and fortunately, I was also able to solve it. The only thing is, my requirement is `nu$Place[ic+1] <- paste(nu$Place[ic], nu$Place[ic+1])`. And that is not a problem too. Thanks for your support.