# Is there a way to use R in a java applet?

Tags: java, r

I want to create a java applet that takes various files and runs statistical tests on them. The user would choose a file and press the appropriate button for a statistical test. All of the statistical tests would be coded in R. Is there a way to "bridge" R and Java?

Comment: Can you run R scripts (code ..whatever) in *any* Java app.?  If so, it is probably possible to run them in an applet. Re the applet itself, a desktop app. launched using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) would be easier to deploy, and provide a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of functionality you are looking for is readily available in R itself. The [Shiny package](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/), created by RStudio, does exactly what you need: provide a web interface to R including simple GUI elements. The advantage of using Shiny is that it takes care of all the nitty gritty details, letting you focus on the analyses. It literally took me 2 hours to install Shiny and create my first web app.

Disclaimer: I do not have any affiliations with RStudio, I'm just a happy user :).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to "bridge" R and Java?

There certainly is. You can use [JRI](http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/JRI/index.shtml).

Here is a JRI Java to R example that I provided in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019654/call-r-from-java-to-get-chi-squared-statistic-and-p-value/16020281#16020281) (passing a double array  and having R sum it):

```
// Start R session.
Rengine re = new Rengine (new String [] {"--vanilla"}, false, null);

// Check if the session is working.
if (!re.waitForR()) {
  return;
}

re.assign("x", new double[] {1.5, 2.5, 3.5});
REXP result = re.eval("(sum(x))");
System.out.println(result.asDouble());
re.end();
```

The above is basically the equivalent of doing this in R:

```
x <- c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5)
sum(x)
```

Note: If you're using Eclipse and JRI I highly recommend [this plugin](http://www.studytrails.com/RJava-Eclipse-Plugin/) to set it up.

---

Alternatively you just create R scripts that you execute from Java using `RScript.exe`. For example:

```
Rscript my_script.R
```

You will find plenty of information on the internet explaining how to execute command line commands from Java. I don't know enough about it to give you an example.