# Call parameters from JAVA code in R code to dynamically pass csv file and unique ID

Tags: java, r

I have a R script in which I want to call parameters from Java code. The parameters are `csv file name` file name and `unique ID` which has to be used to name the two output files.

My R script is :

```
 df1 <- read.csv("filename.csv")
 vs=colnames(df1)
 md=formula(paste(vs[3],"~",vs[1],"+",vs[2]))
 fit <- summary(aov(md, data=df1))[[1]]

 #text output   
 names(fit)[1:4]=c("DF","SS","MS","F")
 sink("test.txt")
```

In this code the first line `df1 <- read.csv("filename.csv")` should take file name dynamically from `JAVA code` and the last line `sink("test.txt")` should take `unique ID` and create the output file.

The java code is :

```
buildCommand.add("Rscript  ");  
buildCommand.add(scriptName);
buildCommand.add(inputFileWithPathExtension);
buildCommand.add(uniqueIdForR);
```

I have seen other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019654/call-r-from-java-to-get-chi-squared-statistic-and-p-value) but I am unsure wether it will help in my case, also similar posts talking about `rJava` package`, but didn't get clear idea.

Any help will be highly appreciated. thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read command line parameters from an R script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script)

Comment: Once you make sure that the final system command looks like `Rscript scriptName inputFile uniqueId`, you only have to handle the command line parameters in R, which is not Java specific.

Comment: @RalfStubner Im new to this, so should it be something like this `args <- commandArgs(TRUE)` `input <- read.csv(args[1])`.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.

Comment: @RalfStubner How should I use the unique ID that is passed as argument in java code to name the output file in R. Should it be added as another argument like `unique_Id <- as.integer(args[2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a very simple example for reading command line arguments in your case:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
input <- args[1]
output <- paste0(args[2], ".txt")

cat("Reading from", input, "\n")
cat("Writing to", output, "\n")
```

Example:

```
$ Rscript foo.R foo.csv 1234567
Reading from foo.csv 
Writing to 1234567.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: Im getting an error : `Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) :
 <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1:  ~  +
  ^`   in the line                                                                           
 `vs=colnames(df1)
md=formula(paste(vs[3],"~",vs[1],"+",vs[2]))`

Comment: @K.S This looks as if the `vs[i]` are empty. You probably should add a test like `any(nchar(vs[1:3]) == 0)`. If that is `TRUE` you should stop execution and output `vs`.

Comment: This error was not there earlier when the input file was hard coded. Is it because of this line `df1 <- input`.

Comment: That line should probably read `df1 <- read.csv(input)`. And in the end you should have `sink(output)`.

Comment: Will try the following. Also for output I have .svg as image, can i add it as  `output <- paste0(args[2], ".txt", ''.svg")`

Comment: @K.S You probably want `output1 <- paste0(args[2], ".txt")` and `output2 <- paste0(args[2], ".svg")`. But I am not 100% sure what your aim is.

Comment: My aim is to pass `input file` dynamically to R script and name the output files `.txt` and `.svg` as unique ID. Both `input file` and `unique ID` are arguments from `Java` code. Further the R script is for various statistical analysis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177509/discussion-between-ralf-stubner-and-k-s).