# Performing the same action on multiple files

Tags: r

I have multiple files in a single folder and I'd like to perform the same action each file using R, without just changing the file name in my script every time. In particular, I have 26 .csv files that I need to identify duplicate entries in individually. Any advice on the best way to do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `list.files` within an `lapply`.
For example, I think something like this is a good start:

```
 res <- lapply(list.files(path=FILES_DIRECTORY,
                              pattern='*.csv',  ## I look for csv files, 
                              full.names=T),    ## to get full names path+filename
                   function(file){ ff <- read.csv(file)
                                   ff[duplicated(ff),]
                   })
```

You can also name the resulted list with file names.

```
  names(res) <- gsub('[.]csv','',
                      list.files(path=FILES_DIRECTORY,pattern='*.csv'))
```

Comment: I believe you could avoid having to name the list in a separate command if you use `sapply` with `USE.NAMES=TRUE` instead of `lapply`.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde yes you can use `sapply` here even you don't get a pretty name( you will get full path names). Personally, I rarely use `sapply` and I prefer using `lapply`.

Comment: Wonderful, I can't wait to try it. Thank you both for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should make this treatment done by the calling terminal with something like :

```
R --save --args *.csv < myScript.R
```

See [How can I read command line parameters from an R script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script)