# Command Line arguments in R

Tags: r, command-line-arguments

I'd like to know if it's possible to pass a string as a command line argument to execute in R?

I've attempted it already and I think it's parsing based on space, regardless of quotation marks.

```
./R_Script.r abc.bed def.bed "cat bedgraph 1,2"
```

Comment: You can look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be parsing based on space. I'm also not sure why you are trying to execute your R script file directly, rather than using `Rscript` and passing the script file. If your `R_Script.r` file contains only one line: `commandArgs()`, then running this line:

```
Rscript --vanilla R_Script.r "first second"
```

should get you:

```
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/bin/exec/R" "--slave"
[3] "--no-restore"                "--vanilla"
[5] "--file=R_Script.r"           "--args"
[7] "first second"
```

As you can see, the 7th element of the list is `first second`, so it isn't parsing the space.

Comment: Thanks, Rscript is a much better method than executing the script directly.