# call RMarkdown on command line using a.R that is passed a file

Tags: r, command-line, automation, argument-passing, r-markdown

In summary, I am using my script 'Graphs.R' on 'input_file1.txt' in RStudio to create a Rmd which I then knit to html. I would like to automate this process to run more files on the command line.

So far, I can get the Rscript to run on the command line using:

> Rscript Graphs.R input_file1.txt

I also know that I can create an .RMD file using:

> Rscript -e rmarkdown::render(Graphs.R)

However, I would like to do the following:

> Rscript -e rmarkdown::render('Graphs.R input_file1.txt', 'output_file.Rmd')

are there any ideas as how to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. What is the result of the first script?

Comment: Graphs.R creates tables and graphs of the data in 'input_file1.txt' for example, kable(df) and some bar graphs with tables inserted to give summary statistics for the data.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. It seems like you have a text file which has to be converted to an Rmd by an R script (why isn't it just an Rmd to begin with?) and then you want to render the Rmd. You can do this by running these commands in your terminal:

```
Rscript Graphs.R
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('output_file.Rmd')"
```

The first command runs the `Graphs.R` file which presumably generates `output_file.Rmd`. The second command runs a one-liner which knits `output_file.Rmd` into `output_file.html`.

If you want to read command line arguments in an R file, try ?`commandArgs`.

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
```

Also see this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script).