# Run RMarkdown with arguments on the command line

Tags: r, bash, r-markdown

I'm trying to run a Rmarkdown file (`myfile.Rmd`) from the command line terminal. This file needs to take an argument to work. We can use this simple file as an example:

````
---
title: "Simple example"
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r read_arg, include=FALSE}
args = commandArgs(TRUE)
VAR = args[1]
```

```{r show_var}
VAR
```
````

So, first of all, is it possible to run a Rmarkdown file by reading arguments as done for Rscripts? I mean, not by reading input files as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479130/passing-parameters-to-r-markdown) question.

If so, how can it be done? I hope that the piece of work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507693/call-rmarkdown-on-command-line-using-a-r-that-is-passed-a-file) used to run a Rmarkdown file worked for me, but it doesn't because of the argument. I'm trying to run something like:

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('myfile.Rmd myarg')"
```

**EDIT:** But it gives the following error:

> Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute(input) : 
>         file 'myfile.Rmd_myarg' does not exist
>       Calls:  -> setwd -> dirname -> 
>       Además: Warning messages:
>       1: In normalizePath(path, winslash = winslash, mustWork = mustWork) :
>         path[1]="myfile.Rmd myarg": No existe el fichero o el directorio
>       2: In normalizePath(path, winslash = winslash, mustWork = mustWork) :
>         path[1]="myfile.Rmd_myarg": No existe el fichero o el directorio
>       Ejecución interrumpida

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You pass parameters to `render` using the `params` argument. Also, put a comma between the file name and any arguments.

Comment: It seems I can run `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('example.Rmd',params=list('myarg'))"
`. The PDF file is now generated. I'm just wondering why it prints "NA" instead of "myarg", as expected

Comment: Add `myarg` to the parameters of the `RMD` file so it knows to accept them.

Comment: Also, please read the documentation on how to properly pass parameters to a report: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works. Please, feel free to write it into an answer. I will accept it

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Adding the `myarg` object as a parameter is the way to go:

`Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('example.Rmd',params=list(args = myarg))"`

And then add the parameter to your `Rmd` file:

```
---
title: "Simple example"
output:
  pdf_document: default
params:
  args: myarg
---
```

Documentation on parameterized reports here: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html

Comment: Small error in the call to Rscript. Should be args for it to work your suggested Rmd code.

Comment: You're also missing a quotation mark at the end of the `Rscript` command, I can't edit it because it's less than a 6 character edit

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify for those who were confused like me:

The accepted answer implies that the parameter’s value in the YAML header and the parameter’s value in the command line must match. They do not need to match. Whatever `myarg` is, you do not need to add it to the YAML header.

That would defeat the purpose of rendering the report from the command line. Every time you want to change the value of `arg`, you would also need to open the .Rmd and change it in the YAML header.

Simply initializing the parameter in the header, e.g. with an empty string or NA, will suffice. E.g.:

````
---
title: "Simple example"
output:
    pdf_document: default
params:
    args: ''
---

```{r read_arg, include=FALSE}
args <-  params$args
VAR <- args[1]
```

```{r show_var}
VAR
```
````

Arguments passed to the `Rscript` command can then assign the desired value to the parameter by overwriting. E.g.:

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('example.Rmd’, param=list(args=myarg))"
```

I would also note that `myarg` is an argument, whereas `arg` is a parameter.