# Is it possible to create a self-rendering Rmarkdown document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, executable, shebang

For typical R scripts the shebang syntax can be used to run the code within. With a file `file.R`

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

<some R code here>
```

Running `./file.R` will execute the code.

But can somehow the same be done with R-markdown? So that with a file named `file.Rmd`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env <some command>

<some markdown>
<some R code here>
<some markdown again>
```

Running `./file.Rmd` would produce `file.md`?

Comment: Why not have a script that calls `rmarkdown::render` on the Rmd document? Otherwise I'm not sure how a file would know to knit itself

Comment: I cannot think of a way myself, hence the question. But having such a possibility would reduce some boilerplate working on multi-language projects - i.e. no need for separate rules about handling R-markdown files in Makefiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can treat an Rmd file as an Rscript. For instance, assume that your Rmd file looks like this

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "ekoam"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

You can then prepend the following code to that Rmd file

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

args <- commandArgs()
fname <- normalizePath(sub("--file=", "", args[grepl("--file=", args)]))
thisfile <- readLines(fname)
newfname <- paste0(tempdir(), "/", basename(fname))
writeLines(thisfile[-1:-which(thisfile == "q(\"no\")")], newfname)
rmarkdown::render(newfname, output_dir = dirname(fname))
q("no")
```

The trick here is `q("no")`. This line terminates the R session, and, thus, whatever written after it will be ignored. Such an effect also means high flexibility for coding because you can write almost any valid R code before that `q("no")`. The code above simply creates another temporary Rmd file with the same content as what is after `q("no")`. Then, we `rmarkdown::render` that temporary file and dump the output to the current directory.

The complete Rmd file looks like this

````
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

args <- commandArgs()
fname <- normalizePath(sub("--file=", "", args[grepl("--file=", args)]))
thisfile <- readLines(fname)
newfname <- paste0(tempdir(), "/", basename(fname))
writeLines(thisfile[-1:-which(thisfile == "q(\"no\")")], newfname)
rmarkdown::render(newfname, output_dir = dirname(fname))
q("no")

---
title: "Untitled"
author: "ekoam"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: Thank you, I think this is a very clever solution.

Comment: One detail, the shebang should be `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript`, not `#!/usr/bin/env/Rscript`

Comment: Sorry about that. I missed that because I was testing with an absolute path to the Rscript binary. I have corrected that mistake.

Answer (score 2):

> Disclaimer: I do not know much about Linux, nor do I have a Linux machine with R installed available to test my answer. Let me know if this does not work properly. If this inspires someone to write a better answer, I'll happily delete this one.

---

Let me approach this backwards:

- To knit a document, we need to call `rmarkdown::render()`.
- To run this command from a command line, we can use `RScript -e "rmarkdown::render('document.Rmd')"`, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49908054/2706569).
- Probably you [do not want to hardcode the path to `Rscript`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/178771) but use a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` instead.
- The problem with this approach is that [it does not allow to pass arguments to `Rscript`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63979/shebang-line-with-usr-bin-env-command-argument-fails-on-linux).
- I therefore propose to use a "wrapper" in the shebang that is responsible for calling `Rscript`.
- With the name of the RMD file as [argument](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/09/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/), the required R code becomes `rmarkdown::render(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)[1])`.

Step by step:

1. Create the wraper (in any directory that is in your `$PATH`) and [make it executable](https://askubuntu.com/a/229592/572193):

   ```
    touch KnitWrapper.sh
    chmod +x KnitWrapper.sh
   ```
2. Write the following to `KnitWrapper.sh`:

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)[1])" $1
   ```
3. Make sure `Rscript` is in your `$PATH`. If you update R, update your `$PATH` accordingly.
4. In your RMD file, add the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env KnitWrapper.sh`.
5. Make your RMD file executable and run it:

   ```
    chmod +x yourDocument.Rmd
    ./yourDocument.Rmd
   ```

---

Unfortunately, the above is largely untested. Let me know if it does not work, so I can either fix or delete this answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is also a very nice approach, but I decided to go with another answer, as it doesn't depend on maintaining a separate file with instructions about rendering.