# how can i run php+rscript on linux server?is it possible?And if possible then how?

Tags: php, r

```
    //poorman.php
    <?php
    echo "<form action='poorman.php' method='get'>";
    echo "Number values to generate: <input type='text' name='N' />";
    echo "<input type='submit' />";
    echo "</form>";

    if(isset($_GET['N']))
    {
      $N = $_GET['N'];

      // execute R script from shell
      // this will save a plot at temp.png to the filesystem
      exec(".\R\R-3.1.3\bin\Rscript .\R\R-3.1.3\bin\my_rscript.R $N");

      // return image tag
      $nocache = rand();
      echo("<img src='temp.png?$nocache' />");
    }
    ?>
    //my_rscript.R
    args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

    N <- args[1]
    x <- rnorm(N,0,1)

    png(filename="temp.png", width=500, height=500)
    hist(x, col="lightblue")
    dev.off()
```

This is a simple programe in which r script is included in php and run in     localhost.But i wanted to run this code in linux server so how it is possible can anyone explain me please..?

Comment: PHP is never run on the local browser. If it runs an R script, it is also run on the server. So what is the problem here?

Comment: sorry its a localhost not browser.it was typing mistake.actually i wann say that is php+rscript run on ubantu server?

Comment: I don't see there will be any issues if the server also has `R` installed.

Answer (score 0):

Debian or Ubuntu Install R first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Then you got R in your server.

Write your R script called `new.r`

Then execute `shell_exec('Rscript new.r');`

What about passing parameter to R?

Refer to [How can I read command line parameters from an R script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script)

Content of new.r:

```
options(echo=FALSE)
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
print(args)
```

`shell_exec('Rscript new.r Hello');` will return:

```
[1] "Hello"
```