# Running an R function over files in a Bash command line

Tags: r, linux, bash, command-line, rscript

I am trying to iterate a function I have written in R (strandcode.txt) over all of the files in a given directory.

strandcode.txt is shown below, it's a simple function to compute a Chi Squared test.

```
strand <- function(file){
data <- as.data.frame(read.table(file))
colnames(data) <- c('chr', 'pos', 'fwd', 'bkwd')
data$chi <- ((.5 - (data$fwd / (data$fwd + data$bkwd)))^2)/.5
keep <- data[data$chi < .823, ]
return(keep)
}

strand{$i}
```

When I am running this on my Linux server I am using Rscript and iterating over all of the files in the directory by the command below.

```
for i in $( ls ); do Rscript strandcode.txt >> strandout.txt; done
```

However this is giving me the error 
    Error: unexpected '{' in "strand{"
    Execution halted

I have also tried the following command lines (taking the final line out of strandcode.txt)

```
for i in $( ls ); do Rscript strandcode.txt; Rscript strand{$i} >>     strandout.txt; done
for i in $( ls ); do Rscript strandcode.txt strand{$i} >> strandout.txt; done
```

Both run without an error and without outputting anything to my outfile.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `strand{$i}` is not proper R code. Your `$i` is not visible inside the script, so you need to get what bash knows as `$i` into something your script knows about. This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script and the linked page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script/2151627#2151627, where Dirk modifies his recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a pattern that matches only the data files, instead of `$( ls )` which expands to every file in the directory, including `strandcode.txt`.  Assuming you have moved all the data files to a subdirectory called `data/`, you could do

```
for i in data/*; do Rscript -e "source('strandcode.txt'); print(strand('$i'))" >> strandout.txt; done
```

after removing the last line from `strandcode.txt`, which is incorrect as stated in the comments.  This should work as long as the file names don't contain single quotes or other problematic characters.

Comment: Additionally, that's a [useless use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls).