# Pass shell environment variable to Rscript

Tags: r

Is there a way to pass a shell environment variable to Rscript. For example:

```
Rscript -e 'devtools::install_github("private/repo",auth_token = "$GITHUB_CRED")'
```

I've tried this and it just passes the literal character. I'm wondering if there's another way?

Comment: Maybe `auth_token = shell("$GITHUB_CRED", intern = TRUE)`?

Comment: I'm going to give it a shot. I have a hacky solution right now where I'm pushing it to a file and then `readLines()`

Comment: How about args? `Rscript -e 'args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE); paste("bla", args[1])' myPassword`

Comment: @RichScriven I tried both `shell` and `system`, neither worked.

Comment: @zx8754 going to try your solution now too.

Comment: If args option worked then this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a bit ridiculous, but:

```
echo $GITHUB_CRED > file.txt
Rscript -e 'devtools::install_github("private/repo",auth_token = readLines("file.txt"))'
```

I'm using this in jenkins build(s) with docker-slaves-plugin so that I can store all my configuration in Dockerfiles associated with my package repositories (clean builds)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Sys.getenv`?

```
Rscript -e 'devtools::install_github("private/repo", auth_token=Sys.getenv("GITHUB_CRED"))'
```

Comment: Does `Sys.getenv` retrieve the correct value? You can check by printing it out.

Comment: It worked for me as long as I `export`ed the environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

In the narrow sense of the question: "yes, Rscript can":

```
edd@max:~$ SOME_VAR="some value" Rscript -e 'print(Sys.getenv("SOME_VAR"))'
[1] "some value"
edd@max:~$
```

As for dealing with GitHub credentials, there are probably better solutions available via the proper GitHub clients.  Did you try the (excellent and recommended) [git2r](https://cran.r-project.org/package=git2r) package?

Comment: No, I haven't tried `git2r`. I think the main problem, unstated, is that I'm passing it as an environment variable to a Dockerfile that's being built by a CI system. So none of the more conventional approaches are working.

Comment: I am no security expert but some people have worked in that space. Don't reinvent the wheel -- do some google search around Docker, git, credentials, ...

Comment: Even Docker doesn't have a well-defined strategy for sharing secrets. Everything right now is just a hack with security issues. For your reading pleasure https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13490