# Using lapply to source multiple R scripts in sub-directories

Tags: r

These are the folders in my directory

```
128    128-1-32  16384    16384-1-36  4096-1     512    512-1-65  65536-1
128-1  128tbw1   16384-1  4096        4096-1-36  512-1  65536
```

Each of them has a7.R code that loads files from each folder and creates images.I want my script to enter each of the folders then

```
source('a7.R')
```

then exit that folder and repeat the process for all the folders.I am doing this now manually and it is really boring.Is this possible with R?

I have tried solution like this

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

 lapply(list.files(full.names=TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = "^a7\\.R$"), source)

milenko@milenko-desktop:~/jbirp/mt07$ Rscript s.R
list()
```

The `coffeinejunky`'s solution is not working

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

foo <- function(directory) { setwd(directory); source(a7.R) }
do.call("foo", list(directory= 128 128-1-32  16384 16384-1-36  4096-1 512 512-1-65 65536-1  128-1 128tbw1 16384-1  4096 4096-1-36  512-1  65536))

    source('n.R')
Error in source("n.R") : n.R:2:33: unexpected numeric constant
1: foo <- function(directory) { setwd(directory); source(a7.R) }
2: do.call("foo", c(directory= 128 128
```

If i change list like this

```
   do.call("foo", list(directory= "./128" "./128-1" "./128-1-32" "./128tbw1" "./16384" "./16384-1" "./16384-1-36" "./4096" "./4096-1" "./4096-1-36"  "./512" "./512-1" "./512-1-65" "./65536" "./65536-1"))
```

I got

```
Error in source("n.R") : n.R:2:40: unexpected string constant
1: foo <- function(directory) { setwd(directory); source(a7.R) }
2: do.call("foo", list(directory= "./128" "./128-1"

                        ^
```

This is what I got when I list path

```
> list.dirs(path = ".", full.names = TRUE)
 [1] "."            "./128"        "./128-1"      "./128-1-32"   "./128tbw1"   
 [6] "./16384"      "./16384-1"    "./16384-1-36" "./4096"       "./4096-1"    
[11] "./4096-1-36"  "./512"        "./512-1"      "./512-1-65"   "./65536"     
[16] "./65536-1"
```

I need to change directory multiple times and perform the same operation in each of them.Is lapply good for this or not?

Comment: Something like `for(myDir in dirVec) source(paste(myDir, "a7.R", sep="/"))` should do the trick.

Comment: Try `lapply(list.files(recursive = TRUE, pattern = "^a7\\.R$"), source)`

Comment: Every folder has a7.R file, is this script doing something specific only to that folder, or is it the same script but with different data, i.e.: input file formats are the same in all those folders?

Comment: @zx8754 Input formats are the same in all those folders!

Comment: Then this is a possible duplicate of - [How can I read command line parameters from an R script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script) , meaning you need to pass folder name to one main `a7.R` script, e.g.: `Rscript a7.R 128`

Comment: @zx8754 I forgot to tell that I am on Ubuntu!

Comment: @zx8754 I do not know how to solve my problem.I need to cd 128,than source('a7.R').

Comment: @plannapus The same,I will edit my post.

Comment: @coffeinjunky Please take a look at my edit,not working!

Comment: Why are you running Rscript?

Comment: @coffeinjunky It is the same unfortunately!

Comment: @coffeinjunky No,it can not recognize string content!!

Comment: @coffeinjunky With coma I got,Error in foo("128", "128-1", "128-1-32", "128tbw1", "16384", "16384-1",  : 
  unused arguments ("128-1", "128-1-32", "128tbw1", "16384", "16384-1", "16384-1-36", "4096", "4096-1", "4096-1-36", "512", "512-1", "512-1-65", "65536", "65536-1")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
directories <- list.dirs(path=".", full.names = T)
# you need to make sure this contains the relevant directories
# otherwise you need to remove irrelevant directories

foo <- function(x) {
  old <- setwd(x) # this stores the old directory and changes into the new one
  source("a7.R")
  setwd(old) 
}

lapply(directories, foo)
```

Alternatively,

```
for(folder in directories) foo(folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will source every `a7.R` file with the working directory temporarily set to the sourced file's folder.

```
a7files <- list.files(full.names=TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = "^a7\\.R$")
sapply(a7files, source, chdir = TRUE)
```

---

From `?source`

> `chdir` logical; if `TRUE` and `file` is a pathname, the R working directory is temporarily changed to the directory containing `file` for evaluating.