# Multiple Value for command line option in R

Tags: r, shell

I am writing a code in R and I want to input values through the command line.
I am using get opt and I intend to read the values as such:

ScriptName -n File1 File2 -w 2...

I need an option which can read more than one value, in this case more than one file name, but I discovered that getopt doesn't allow this.

Any idea or any other package that will allow this?

Comment: What exactly are your requirements? You can access all the parameters with `commandArgs()`. Just asking for straight up package recommendations is considered off-topic. Try to more specifically specify your exact problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2151212/680068

Comment: Yeah I can use commandArgs() but I want to input multiple values so I want it to be organized and clearer this is why I tried using Getopt. So I want to the user to input several variable such as names of files and numbers from the terminal