# How to use stdin in R

Tags: r, bash, bioinformatics

I have an R script I am trying to run through in a bash script but im not sure how to make the two compatible 
my R script(seq_trimming.R):

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

input <- file('stdin','r')
row <- readLines(input, n=1)
while (length(row)>0) {


#loading reads
#path needs to go to .ab1 
seq.filepath = row 
seq.abif = read.abif(seq.filepath)
seq.sanger = sangerseq(seq.abif)

#trimming low quality bases
#you can control the severity of the trim by usuing (seq.abif, 0.01) the     higher the number the less amount of bases are trimmed
trims = trim.mott(seq.abif, 0.001)
trims
}
```

while my bash script is

```
ls *.ab1 | while read line
do
cd ../../sanger_analysis | Rscript seq_trimming.R $line >../../sanger_analysis/trim_$line
done
```

my goal is to be able to take a group of ab1 files in a folder and put them through this script and get the trimmed sequences out

Comment: Is the problem that your R script doesn't get your $line variable, i.e. the command line argument?

Comment: do `args <- commandArgs()`, then `$line` would be `args[1]` inside your R script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script

Comment: `stdin` in this case is the output of `cd`, which is nothing. You shouldn't need `cd` at all since this is working on all of the files in the current directory.