# How to get a user input in command prompt and pass it to R

Tags: r, windows, command-line-arguments

I am trying to use

```r
var <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Enter a number: "))
```

and later use this in a calculation.

It works fine when running in RStudio but I need to be able to pass this input from the command line in Windows 10
I am using a batch file with a single line

```
Rscript.exe "C:\My Files\R_scripts\my_script.R"
```

When it gets to the user input part it freezes and it doesn't provide expected output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read command line parameters from an R script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script)

Comment: `readline` only waits for user input if run on its own. You are running a full script so it will run until the end of the script and assign `NA` to `var`.

Comment: I imagine because executing via Rscript doesn't give you an interactive environment - as automated scripts will never proceed. See the the help on `?readline` example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation of `readline()`:

> This can only be used in an interactive session. [...] In non-interactive use the result is as if the response was RETURN and the value is "".

For non-interactive use - when calling R from the command line - I think you've got two options:

1. Use `readLines(con = "stdin", n = 1)` to read user input from the terminal.
2. Use `commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)` to supply the input as an argument from the command line when calling the script instead.

Under is more information.

### 1. Using `readLines()`

`readLines()` looks very similar to `readline()` which you're using, but is meant to read files line by line. If we instead of a file points it to the standard input (`con = "stdin"`) it will read user input from the terminal. We set `n = 1` so that it stops reading from the command line when you press Enter (that is, it only read **one** line).

##### Example

Use `readLines()` in a R-script:

```r
# some-r-file.R

# This is our prompt, since readLines doesn't provide one
cat("Please write something: ")
args <- readLines(con = "stdin", n = 1)

writeLines(args[[1]], "output.txt")
```

Call the script:

```sh
Rscript.exe "some-r-file.R"
```

It will now ask you for your input. Here is a screen capture from PowerShell, where I supplied "Any text!".

[image: Print screen from PowerShell]

Then the output.txt will contain:

```
Any text!
```

---

### 2. Using`commandArgs()`

When calling an `Rscript.exe` from the terminal, you can add extra arguments. With `commandArgs()` you can capture these arguments and use them in your code.

##### Example:

Use `commandArgs()` in a R-script:

```r
# some-r-file.R
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

writeLines(args[[1]], "output.txt")
```

Call the script:

```sh
Rscript.exe "some-r-file.R" "Any text!"
```

Then the output.txt will contain:

```
Any text!
```

Comment: ok. but how can I make it so that the user gets a prompt and then enters a value which will later be used?

Comment: I did some more research, and have updated my answer with a solution for that. I think this should solve your problem. Please let me know how it went.